# Is there extension for safari to switch User Agent automatically for specified sites

Tags: safari, user-agent

I am looking for an extension or plugin that will send the iPad User Agent String when I view CNN, Facebook, Youtube, Vimeo so that I get HTML5 content instead of Flash content.

I am aware of the functionality to manually change the User Agent through the develop menu and looking for something that will do it automatically every time I visit certain websites.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only change the user-agent one time for all the browsing session.